# tr/regex c++ library - definition of regex pattern

Tags: c++, regex, tr1

How should i define the regex pattern, when i use the tr1/regex library?

```
#include <tr1/regex>

const regex pattern("[^-]-[^-]");
```

is not working... When compiling i get error: ‘regex’ does not name a type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`regex` is in the `tr1` namespace so you either need to declare that you are using `tr1` or specify that `regex` is in the `tr1` namespace:

```
using namespace tr1;
```

or

```
const tr1::regex pattern("[^-]-[^-]");
```